# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: After granting user permission to EXECUTE package

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc, oracle12c

I've spent months developing a JAVA application with a Oracle db back-end.  I am using Netbeans as my IDE and Oracle 12c on a laptop as my database. All PL/SQL has been compiled with no errors.

After extensive testing (logged in as the schema owner), I attempted to add a user.  I created the user, logged in as SYS_DBA, using `CREATE USER E566299 IDENTIFIED BY tempPswrd`, then granted permission using `GRANT CREATE SESSION` and `GRANT EXECUTE ON C##FAI_CODE.FAI_ADMIN_PKG TO E566299` and received `Grant succeeded` confirmation.

I login to my application, as this new user, with no errors using the following:

```
private static Connection getDbConn(String user, String password) throws SQLException{
        OracleDataSource ods = null;
        Connection dbConn = null;
        user = "c##" + user;
            ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1522/orcl.global.ds.XXXXXXXX.com");
            ods.setUser(user);
            ods.setPassword(password);
            dbConn = ods.getConnection();
        return dbConn;
    }
```

Then it throws an error on the first package procedure call:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
>       PLS-00201: identifier 'FAI_ADMIN_PKG.CHECK_USER_FOLLOWED' must be declared
>       ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:210)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:53)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3923)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5617)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
>           at faidb.FAIdb.checkSubscription(FAIdb.java:549)
>           at faidb.faidbUI.run(faidbUI.java:186)
>           at faidb.faidbLogin$3.run(faidbLogin.java:133)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)

I'm at a loss, I've tried every possible combination of grant wording, all caps, all lowercase, single quotes, double quotes, with the schema owner name prefix `C##FAI_CODE.FAI_ADMIN_PKG`, without `FAI_ADMIN_PKG`, nothing will allow this new user to execute the package.

I've spent considerable time on this project and am near panic that no one will be able to use it.

Question:

Why can't my newly created user execute a package after being granted permission?

Edit:

I get a `NullPointerException` on the last line with the call to `rset.close();`, the result set is never initialized but it doesn't throw a `SQLException`

```
public Vector<String> fillBox() throws SQLException, NullPointerException{
        CallableStatement callStatement = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        String fillBox = "{call fai_admin_pkg.get_end_item_pn(?)}";
        Vector<String> boxFill = new Vector<>();
        try{
            callStatement = conn.prepareCall(fillBox); 
            callStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callStatement.execute();
            rset = (ResultSet) callStatement.getObject(1); 
            boxFill = buildRsVector(rset);
        }
        finally{
            callStatement.close();
            rset.close();
        }
        return boxFill;
    }
```

That is called here:

```
Vector<String> boxFill = new Vector<>();
            try{
                boxFill = uiInst.fillBox();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e.getMessage());
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here are my permissions as the new user...which do not include execute on the package??  I'm not understanding
[image: no permission after granted]

Comment: Can you perform all of the actions in SQL*Plus and post the results here?  That would help rule out any Java issues.

Comment: I created the user and granted the permissions in SQL plus.  The exceptions being thrown are all from sql, so I assumed it to be a database problem.  I debugged my java code to find out exactly where the problem is

Comment: It's thrown on the first call to a package procedure

Comment: An example of a working call from SQL*Plus logged in as the new user would certainly help.  As would the actual Java code you're using to call the procedure (or function?)  The fact that Oracle strongly discourages the use of the # sign in unquoted identifiers http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm makes the choice of username problematic.  Posting the results of querying `dba_source` for the particular `object_name`, `owner`, and `procedure_name` would be helpful to show how the identifiers are actually created.

Comment: The code you posted would only potentially work if you were logged in to the schema that owned the package or if you set the `current_schema` for the session to the owner of the package or if you had a local or global synonym for the package.  Do you have any of those things in place?  If not, you'd need the schema prefix included.  If you make that change, it probably at least tweaks the error message.  Then post the `dba_procedure` info (sorry, not `dba_source`, brain fart on my part).

Comment: by schema prefix you mean the owner?  Such as : c##fai_code.fai_admin_pkg.<procedure name>?

Comment: "if you set the current_schema for the session to the owner of the package or if you had a local or global synonym for the package"  Do you know of a tutorial to accomplish this?  Let me know if I'm on the right track;  if I want to be able to access this package with a user other than the owner, I need to prefix ALL procedure calls with the package owner name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.  Not having a global synonym set or `current_schema` for the new user's session set to the package owner results in any calls to the owners package procedures requiring the owner's prefix: `<package owner>.<package>.<procedure>`.  The calls I was making under the new user were only to `<package>.<procedure>` resulting in a `SQLException` being thrown because to the compiler that package doesn't exist.

Additionally, I will research both global synonyms and user sessions to avoid having to use this quick fix.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

create session just allow you to login to the database.
you might need others permission to do what you want to do.

you can refer to this link for help

https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html